# for a global var inside click() event i get the incremented value but outside i get default value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

```
var main=function(){
  var p=0;
$('#plus').click(function(){
  p++;
  $('#txt').text(p);//inside event handler
});
$('#val').text(p);//outside eventhandler
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

[image: img]

Comment: Why would it be the same if the value of `p` is only changing upon `click` event?

Comment: because `p` increment only whwn `click` event trigerred but outside code ran before the event trigerred.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, you are assigning value to `#val` on page load and you increment it on click, but do not reassign updated value to `#val`. I have added a `setInterval` which logs value of `p` every second for demo purpose.

```js
var main = function() {
  var p = 0;
  $('#plus').click(function() {
    p++;
    $('#txt').text(p); //inside event handler
  });
  $('#val').text(p); //outside eventhandler
  
  var count = 0;
  
  // Test function to log value of "p" every second.
  var interval = setInterval(function(){
    count++;
    console.log(p)
    
    // Clear interval on a threshold, so as to not spam with events.
    if(count>100)
      window.clearInterval(interval);
  }, 1000)
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="txt" ></p>
<button id="plus">Plus</button>
<p id="val" ></p>
```